# My function doesnt seem to run concurrently here

Tags: go

I tried to speed up a process in my go app (still learning this language) and I already thougt I could freely code without having to look up stuff but seems like I am doing something wrong here.

Inside my main function I created a test to check how fast I ll get the desired outputs and the log shows up like its synchronously instead of concurrent. All the printF are going one after the other. Is there some kind of error I am making here?

```
func main() {
//get all ticker for quote market (returns slice of *binance.BookTicker)
tickers, error := GetTickers("USDT")
if error != nil {
    fmt.Print(error)
}
fmt.Printf("ticker count: %v", len(tickers))
wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
wg.Add(len(tickers))

//iterate over tickers
for _, ticker := range tickers {
    go func(ticker *binance.BookTicker) {
        defer wg.Done()
        ohlcv, _ := GetOHLCV(ticker.Symbol, "4h")
        rsi := RSI(ohlcv)
        fmt.Printf("RSI %v : %v", ticker.Symbol, rsi)

    }(ticker)
}

wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: `Printf` does not run concurrently to prevent multiple write attempts from corrupting the output.  All goroutines and the other calls in those goroutines are running concurrently.

Comment: Oh I didnt know. So all is good? How can I output everything concurrently then tho

Comment: You are already doing it. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: Faster output to console cause it seems slow as sequential

Comment: You are limited by the console output speed. Create a file for each goroutine, and it can write them concurrently.